# regex for a string only contains small letters

Tags: java, regex

Hi I am trying to find a regEx which only accepts lower case letters nothing else,

I tired few options nothing worked, Can some one please guide me :

here are the expressions I tried :

```
(?=.*[a-z])--> this is not working if we have "aaaAA"

[a-z]+^[A-Z]

^[A-Z]+[a-z]+^[A-Z]
```

Please help me.

Comment: You may use `s.matches("[a-z]*")`

Comment: this is accepting Upper case letters as well..

Comment: If it is then why did you accept `[a-z]+`?

Comment: I didn't accepted  [a-z]+, I accepted "^[a-z]+$", Can you please remove - for my question..

Comment: You do not need `"^[a-z]+$"` with `matches()`, `[a-z]+` is enough.

Comment: "aaaAAA" and "AAAaaa" is not working with this "[a-z]+",

Comment: [You are wrong](https://ideone.com/RGeAte).

Comment: Can you explain me how?

Comment: See my link in the previous comment.

Comment: I'm not using String.matches, my requirement is to use Pattern

Comment: Yes, `Pattern.compile("[a-z]+").matcher(s).matches()`. Works as expected. As per the requirement.

Comment: agreed with you , any way I accepted that answer only right, why - for my question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try just [a-z]+

See example here:
https://regex101.com/r/wCdBue/1

If you want to check if whole line / text contains only lowercase letter you should wrap your regex with ^$ like this: ^[a-z]+$

Example:
https://regex101.com/r/T0DHY4/1

Comment: s= "aaaAAAA" is failing :(

Comment: What do you mean by failing?

Comment: Oh I see... you probably want to check if whole line / text contains only lowercase letter. In this case you should wrap your regex with ^$ like this: ^[a-z]+$

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is nearly correct. The regex must say "[a-z]+"—include a quantifier, which means that you are not matching a single character, but one or more lowercase characters.

String regex = "[a-z]+";

Here is a quantifier regex link.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me like this:

```
  String line = "aaaA";
  System.out.println(line.matches("^[a-z]+$")); //false
  line = "aaaa";
  System.out.println(line.matches("^[a-z]+$")); //true
```